# NullPointerException trying to setProgress(int)

Tags: java, android, progress, android-progressbar

i have a Fragment in my app which uses ProgressBar, the circle one.
My fragment is:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,
            container, false);
    getActivity().setTitle(R.string.title_home);
    ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressBar.setProgress(100);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


    TextView text = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView);
    text.setText("TEST");
}
```

I've tried using `progressBar.setProgress(50);` in both onActivityCreated and onCreateView. But i still get a NullPointerException.

Logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{stin1.ngt.nextgentelruter/stin1.ngt.nextgentelruter.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ProgressBar.setProgress(int)' on a null object reference
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ProgressBar.setProgress(int)' on a null object reference
     at stin1.ngt.nextgentelruter.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:56)
     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2053)
     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:894)
     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:834)
     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1452)
     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6005)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

When i try to setText on a TextView it's working. Why does it not work to set the Progress?

XML:

```
<stin1.ngt.nextgentelruter.CircleProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/custom_progressBar"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            app:progress="35"
            app:progressBarThickness="4dp"/>
```

I also have the class: CircleProgressBar.java

```
public class CircleProgressBar extends View {


    /**
     * ProgressBar's line thickness
     */
    private float strokeWidth = 4;
    private float progress = 0;
    private int min = 0;
    private int max = 100;
    /**
     * Start the progress at 12 o'clock
     */
    private int startAngle = -90;
    private int color = Color.DKGRAY;
    private RectF rectF;
    private Paint backgroundPaint;
    private Paint foregroundPaint;

    public float getStrokeWidth() {
        return strokeWidth;
    }

    public void setStrokeWidth(float strokeWidth) {
        this.strokeWidth = strokeWidth;
        backgroundPaint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
        foregroundPaint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();//Because it should recalculate its bounds
    }

    public float getProgress() {
        return progress;
    }

    public void setProgress(float progress) {
        this.progress = progress;
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getMin() {
        return min;
    }

    public void setMin(int min) {
        this.min = min;
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getMax() {
        return max;
    }

    public void setMax(int max) {
        this.max = max;
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(int color) {
        this.color = color;
        backgroundPaint.setColor(adjustAlpha(color, 0.3f));
        foregroundPaint.setColor(color);
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }

    public CircleProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        rectF = new RectF();
        TypedArray typedArray = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs,
                R.styleable.CircleProgressBar,
                0, 0);
        //Reading values from the XML layout
        try {
            strokeWidth = typedArray.getDimension(R.styleable.CircleProgressBar_progressBarThickness, strokeWidth);
            progress = typedArray.getFloat(R.styleable.CircleProgressBar_progress, progress);
            color = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.CircleProgressBar_progressbarColor, color);
            min = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.CircleProgressBar_min, min);
            max = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.CircleProgressBar_max, max);
        } finally {
            typedArray.recycle();
        }

        backgroundPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        backgroundPaint.setColor(adjustAlpha(color, 0.3f));
        backgroundPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        backgroundPaint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);

        foregroundPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        foregroundPaint.setColor(color);
        foregroundPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        foregroundPaint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawOval(rectF, backgroundPaint);
        float angle = 360 * progress / max;
        canvas.drawArc(rectF, startAngle, angle, false, foregroundPaint);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        final int height = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
        final int width = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        final int min = Math.min(width, height);
        setMeasuredDimension(min, min);
        rectF.set(0 + strokeWidth / 2, 0 + strokeWidth / 2, min - strokeWidth / 2, min - strokeWidth / 2);
    }

    /**
     * Lighten the given color by the factor
     *
     * @param color  The color to lighten
     * @param factor 0 to 4
     * @return A brighter color
     */
    public int lightenColor(int color, float factor) {
        float r = Color.red(color) * factor;
        float g = Color.green(color) * factor;
        float b = Color.blue(color) * factor;
        int ir = Math.min(255, (int) r);
        int ig = Math.min(255, (int) g);
        int ib = Math.min(255, (int) b);
        int ia = Color.alpha(color);
        return (Color.argb(ia, ir, ig, ib));
    }

    /**
     * Transparent the given color by the factor
     * The more the factor closer to zero the more the color gets transparent
     *
     * @param color  The color to transparent
     * @param factor 1.0f to 0.0f
     * @return int - A transplanted color
     */
    public int adjustAlpha(int color, float factor) {
        int alpha = Math.round(Color.alpha(color) * factor);
        int red = Color.red(color);
        int green = Color.green(color);
        int blue = Color.blue(color);
        return Color.argb(alpha, red, green, blue);
    }

    /**
     * Set the progress with an animation.
     * Note that the {@link android.animation.ObjectAnimator} Class automatically set the progress
     * so don't call the {@link CircleProgressBar#setProgress(float)} directly within this method.
     *
     * @param progress The progress it should animate to it.
     */
    public void setProgressWithAnimation(float progress) {

        ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "progress", progress);
        objectAnimator.setDuration(1500);
        objectAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        objectAnimator.start();
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your layout, your progress element is identified as `custom_progressBar` not `progressBar`.

Try to change this:

```
ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
```

For this:

```
ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.custom_progressBar);
```

Comment: Just figured it out. My bad, i need some sleep. Thanks!

Comment: If it's correct, please accept my answer :)

Comment: Needed to wait 10 minutes :)